# Yii url routing not working on Mac OS X

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii, url-routing

I'm a newbie in php and Yii and this may come across as a very silly question. I am using the Yii framework on Mac OS X to develop a web application. The codebase that I'm working on, was setup on a Windows machine and works perfectly fine on Windows OS. However, when I try running it on my Mac OS X, I get a 404 not found error. There seems to be a problem with url routing in the main.php config file.

My url manager has the following code

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>true,
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(

            '' => 'home',
            'learn-more' => 'home/learn_more',
            'cpi'  => 'cpi/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\[\w\-]+>/<action:\[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\[\w\-]+>/<action:\[\w\-]+>/<code:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\[\w\-]+>/<action:\[\w\-]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

My folder structure looks like this

```
> protected
    > components
    > config
    > controllers
    > views
        > about
        > careers
        > contact
        > cpi
        > devadmin
        > error
        > home
        > info
        > layouts
```

The .htaccess file in the project folder has the following lines of code

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

My homepage http://mysite.com must map to /home/index (i.e, index action in the HomeController), which works perfectly. Each of the other folders under 'views' has an index.php file. I need to map the url of type http://mysite.com/devadmin to /devadmin/index. The existing rules work perfectly when running under Windows OS but give me an error on my Mac OS. I'm wondering if there is any windows specific code in my url manager. I'd be glad if someone could suggest me a solution to this.

Comment: Do you have a devadmin controller? It doesn't map straight to a View folder it maps to a controller and an action, the action the renders a view.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes I do have a devadmin controller (DevadminController.php) in the controllers folder which has an action (actionIndex) and this action renders the homepage on successful login. If I use the url http://mysite.com/index.php?r=devadmin/index, then the page renders correctly. I'm trying to find a solution by which I can render the page using the url http://sndev:8080/devadmin.

Comment: Does sndev:8080/devadmin/index work? If so view my answer below.

Comment: If not, do any other pages work like `sndev:8080/careers/index`?

Comment: @Pitchinnate No sndev:8080/devadmin/index does not work. It gives me a 404 Not Found Error. Other pages like sndev:8080/careers/index too do not work. I tried your solution but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Does sndev:8080 even work? My guess is there is something wrong with your Apache vhost setup.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yeah sndev:8080/ does work. It takes me to the home page. Apart from that sndev:8080/index.php?r=devadmin/index works too. But when I do sndev:8080/devadmin, it doest find the index page under devadmin directory.

Comment: Just for fun I would create another page in the root directory like `test.php` and then change your .htaccess and Rewrite Rule to point to `test.php` and see if it works. Just to make sure Rewrite is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'caseSensitive'  => true,
    'urlFormat'      => 'path',
    'rules'          => array(
        ''                                 => 'home',
        'learn-more'                       => 'home/learn_more',
        'cpi'                              => 'cpi/index',
        '<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>'   => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller>/<action>/<code:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

I don't know your requirements. If it won't help you, try to add more details to your question.

Comment: When I go to mysite.com/index.php?r=devadmin/index, the page renders correctly. But I'm trying to render the page using the url mysite.com/devadmin. Can you please tell me any details you require to suggest me a solution?

Comment: The urlmanager above did not work for me though. Since the urlManager mentioned in my question works on a windows machine, I think there might be some code in it which is not applicable to Mac OS and linux OS.

Comment: Yep, I have the same trouble with routes. Searching for solution. =\ There some (I think) troubles in route slashes or some kind of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work for `domain.com/devadmin` without `/index` at the end you need to add another rule to your URL manager:

```
        '' => 'home',
        'learn-more' => 'home/learn_more',
        'cpi'  => 'cpi/index',
        '<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index', //this is the line you need to add
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\[\w\-]+>/<action:\[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\[\w\-]+>/<action:\[\w\-]+>/<code:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\[\w\-]+>/<action:\[\w\-]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to review you host config file. For example in *nix-like OS it has own (one host one file) file, now let's look in

(my, you will have another)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName *ServerName*
    DocumentRoot /home/nick/public_html/sitefolder

    # this one is for any folder without rules
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    # this one for custom folder
    <Directory /home/nick/public_html/sitefolder/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All # this one we need to change!
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is default config file. But you should re-check

1. Server name;
2. Folders \ directories;
3. In your root directory you should set "AllowOverride **All**" it's important, otherwise .htaccess won't work. In our case I mean second directory ( `<Directory /home/nick/public_html/sitefolder/>` ) rule, not first one!

It helped me to get proper url routes work.

PS: Yes, I know that we can change much more to make our host more secure, but now we talking about not working routes (and mod_rewrite) with Yii.